# How do we avoid downvotes without a comment?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

I am not looking for a smarty pants telling me

"Well, just ask a good question"

I see bad questions getting downvoted as well as good questions, without a single comment. The questioner has no clue why that happens, in case it was really a bad question.

When it was a good question, the downvoter can anonymously downvote (or even close-vote), without leaving a comment a reason. I am not saying his identity must be revealed, but at least his reasoning.

This is unacceptable in my eyes.

How could we improve this situation?

Comment: "Ignorantia juris non excusat" - people tend to downvote when a question doesn't respect rules/how-tos. Reading those usually gives appropriate explanation to the OP. Other downvotes also seem "obvious" to downvoters, which is why they don't take time to comment (even when, sometimes, they should). By the way, I did not downvote you, so my comment doesn't count.

Comment: The truth is - a good question does not really get downvoted. Bad ones do.

Comment: When you are really looking for a [tag:discussion], you might not want to include things like, "I am not looking for a smarty pants telling me". It has a bad smell

Comment: @codeMagic see juergen? there goes smarty pants
there is several examples of good questions getting down and close voted. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top

and thanks for the link, I really didn't stumble over it

Comment: But this isn't a good question because it has been discussed to death. Stumbled upon it? I did a simple search

Comment: @Toskan: Actually I almost never see a good question downvoted. Maybe never. And if you find some good ones downvoted from the 7 million question on SO, then maybe this is not really representative. But that is just my experience - and I am not that strong of a SO user

Comment: @juergend see the duplicate of my post

Comment: Downvoted because it's very ranty, inflammatory, and name-calling, instead of being fair and neutral.

Comment: @Cupcake thanks for the feedback

Comment: Btw it is not a duplicate of one or the other. I am asking what solution would there be. It doesn't need to be a comment, it can be anything. Any of your great ideas.

Comment: Can you offer *any* potential feature?

Comment: I was thinking about putting a picture of a cute puppy on the downvote button that gets slaughtered when pressed.

Comment: That's one idea. I would maybe think about keeping your options open though.

Comment: haha :D alright codemagic. Maybe the search for similar posts could be improved, at least for low rep users. E.g. to avoid the duplicate entries, like in my case. That is one way. E.g. have a screen before adding the answer, with all potential similar questions. That is one idea, force people to read similar questions.

Comment: The search, I'm pretty sure, is **exactly the same** for high and low rep users. I would venture to guess that you would find the same results as I did when searching. "Add a screen before", like the pop up you get when asking a question? "Force people" how? Maybe with a help section of how to ask and, again, a pop up when a user starts a question with similar questions? Yes, those are good ideas.

Comment: you got me wrong. When writing a question there is the section "Recommended similar" questions. I think underneath the title you enter. Yes i am actually recommending low rep users to look at those things in a second screen before really posting the question. So you click ask, you see a second screen with the listed questions and parts of their top answer, then you press again to actually submit. The help page does not help at all

Comment: actually the section i am referring to is called "Questions that may already have your answer" this section does not get refreshed when entering the text in the content. It only gets refreshed when entering the title. Which should imho be improved.

Comment: UPVOTED AND PROUD. somebody in SO community should do something about it. Let's the community to make the decision by conducting a survey.

Answer (score 16):

The best way to avoid down votes without a comment is to first avoid taking it personal. This has an effect on your tone, as well as how people will react to you. From the way you worded your question here on meta, if I were to down vote one of your posts, I'd likely avoid commenting, simply because I might feel you'd retaliate instead of trying to understand the problem and how to fix it.

By approaching the voting with a clear head, it's possible for you to leave a comment on your own post as follows:

> Hello. I was wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with this post so that I can edit and improve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

This is much more likely to get a positive response than:

> hey downvoters!!!! suck it!!

I know that's an extreme comment and not *exactly* how you worded your post here, but the tone is that of someone looking for *confrontation* and not *understanding*. Thus, I might not even *leave* a comment, even if I weren't a down voter. I've left comments on such posts, designed to be helpful, and I've walked away feeling pretty disenfranchised, and again, I was just trying to be helpful.

If you're cool in the comments, someone, maybe not the down voter, but *someone* will respond to your comment and help you out. It may even be the down voter, and he or she may even reverse the vote after working with you to make the changes.

With that said, it's quite possible the questions you're referring to aren't bad questions, but perhaps they're just bad for Stack Overflow.  There's a lot of really good and interesting questions that just aren't fit for Q&A but work well on sites more oriented towards discussion and extended back and forth, like Google Groups, *which might be why you're here instead of Google Groups, because there's less noise here and more answers.*

The reason we come to Stack Overflow, the reason we like it so much and consider it a valuable resource, is precisely because of the huge community of users who help push the best Q&A to the top and the not so hot stuff to the bottom. This is really the purpose of voting, to move things that don't belong down to the bottom of the page and the best stuff to the top.

I encourage you to think about those questions and ask if they meet the goal of something that can be answered in one pass, without extended discussion, debate, arguments, polling, and all of the stuff that Stack Exchange has chosen to pass on.  Hope this helps!

Comment: i totally agree with you on my tone.

What I dislike to read though is the part about "This question fits to google groups" this reason to close a question gets used too often. There is not only black and white, but there are gray tones, and there is more than not, an answer, that is better, and more correct, than another one for a specific use case. It is a shame that people start closing these kind of questions, even though there IS a best answer out there.

Comment: @Toskan, in those situations, you have an opportunity to lead. Say something like "Hey, does anyone see how I can edit this to make it fit better?".  Chances are, if it is a borderline case, you and the community could pull it farther back from the line to where folks don't see the problems anymore. Even if you don't think it's off-topic, primarily opinion based, etc, editing to improve still benefits everyone. Some of the best questions I've ever encountered on Stack Exchange started out as borderline questions that were collaboratively edited into true gems. Hope this helps.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just saw a post yesterday that got to -5 fairly quickly. I was almost positive it would get closed soon after (and downvoted further), but I noticed that the asker wasn't confrontational, kept a fairly cool head, and cleaned up their post as much as they could. Sure enough, when I peeked at the question today, not only is it still open, some of the downvotes were removed and now the post score is back to a 0. That's the kind of turnaround we'd like to help facilitate (if not even better).

Comment: @Toskan: this is not positive at all: [*would the down voting and close voting **fanatics** mind to share their off the hook reasoning?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899181/anytime-time-datepicker-triggers-change-event-each-time-an-input-box-is-focuse#comment36798914_23899181) . . . And looks like [there's a pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253809/how-to-redesign-a-function-method-that-is-partly-different#comment37465408_24253809)... :/

Comment: This is an unrealistic advise that does not deal with tons of illogical down votes...and obviously nothing is done about it because of justifications, like yours, for a bad system that has been going for so long.

Comment: @usefulBee there aren't too many situations where we can control the behaviors of others, but we can most certainly control our own behaviors and how we react to every situation. Remember, the voting isn't about the person but instead is about the content.

Comment: @jmort253, downvoting is a behavior, and when it is not followed by a comment, in a lot of cases it is a bad one.  Many people in the past suggested to tie downvoting with a brief comment but unfortunately the dominating gangster culture suppresses those attempts by also downvoting and deletions. While your answer is polite and inspired by good intentions, which I appreciate, but in a culture of gangsters, it could do the opposite.