# How to improve views for a question whose relevant tags are not available

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, answers, asking-questions

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146232/firmware-recovery-for-dynamixel-motor) I need a solution to, but I don't seem to be getting any views. There are no other tags that match my question. I cannot put a bounty. The question is very clear since it highlights the problem, the things I have tried and the things I have a problem with.

[This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146232/firmware-recovery-for-dynamixel-motor) needs to be addressed by me as soon as possible. Is there any way to attract more attention? Or maybe finding a person who can possibly solve this?

[This Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261078/what-do-i-do-if-my-question-has-received-no-answers-or-comments) addresses a similar problem and yet none of the solutions provided help me due to a lack of "reputation".

Comment: More tags don't mean more attention. In fact too many tags may narrow attention.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ
For instance, this question with 5 tags attracted as many views on that question with 3 tags in 2 minutes as compared to 2 days..I believe it does help.

Comment: There are many more factors asides from tags

Comment: @santiago Could you help structure my question?

Comment: Downvoting is anonymous - and complaining about them are a downvote magnet

Comment: Voting on meta is different ....

Comment: *..needs to be addressed by me as soon as possible* then maybe SO isn't the best place to ask your question. We are all volunteers, nobody can be held responsible for (not) answering within your deadline.

Comment: Before things get worse you might want to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#255584) as a precaution.

Comment: @rene I agree with you completely. But if there is a way to reach more people who might have a solution, then I think its worth giving it a try.

Comment: @DhruvReshamwala Also your question asks about a very specific piece of hardware. How many people around here do you expect are actually familiar with it?

Comment: And with regard to explain down votes, [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291104/please-add-a-way-to-prohibit-members-from-down-voting-a-legitimate-question) is the lowest voted question about that among many, many more. Don't go down that route. Voting is anonymous and will remain that way, the label says 'unclear, not useful, no research effort' so it is one of those.

Comment: Because hardware might be involved here consider one of the other SE sites, a quick [search](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=Dynamixel) gives some hits. Before you ask somewhere else check their help center and meta, don't go blindly cross-post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points I find out after reading out your SO question. To get better response make you question very clear in terms to specify your problem and what you tried to overcome that.

The first thing, I noticed is, this problem is about very specific hardware issue, on this hardware many SO users have expertise thats also matter in terms of user response. I am not familiar with the technology you are working on but till now its look like you are not putting any efforts to solve this and trying to get whole solution without any efforts(I am not pointing out you not did't that, but you have to mention those in your question)

Your question does not includes any code or trying efforts in terms of code, many users prefer to answer question where OP already put some efforts himself to solve that problem.

> There are no other tags that match my question.

Second point, You said about tags, If you are not able to find specific tag for your question and you did not have enough reputation to create that, you can mentioned in your question to put some note, and then any user with Create Tag Privilege will add those new tags, if required.

> This problem needs to be addressed by me as soon as possible.

SO is not code writing service platform, you can ask your question here, but there is no guarantee that you are able to get answer within certain timeline. Although, here many users are those are ready to help you anytime.

At last, if you are not able to find any good answer, then you can go to chatroom and discuss there about your specific problem.

Comment: I think his question would have got or would get more answers on electronics.stackexchange

Comment: Actually, I have no idea of that technology so I have no suggestion, but if you have expertise in that technology then vote/flag to migration to different site.

Comment: I'm already out of flags for today and someone else already suggested it on the orignal post